# php prepared statement inserting with trim or date() etc. php strict standards error

Tags: php, session, prepared-statement, mysql-real-escape-string

Hopefully a very easy question, but I haven't been able to find the answer.  I'm learning to use prepared statements rather than mysqli_escape. I have the code:

```
$stmt = $dbc->prepare("SELECT something FROM the_table WHERE email=? ");
$stmt->bind_param("s", strtolower(trim($_REQUEST['email'])));
```

I get the error message "PHP Strict Standards:  Only variables should be passed by reference in".

Am I correct in thinking that you're not supposed to use strtolower / trim etc in the bind param line? Is this important? Is it less secure to first have a separate:

```
   $email = strtolower(trim($_REQUEST['email'])));
```

I kind of thought I should try and keep the $_POST, $_REQUEST bits actually in the bind_param line.

I also get the same issue in another page with:

```
$stmt->bind_param("s", date("Y-m-d") );
```

Lastly and **separately**, is it safe to use insert a `$_SESSION` variable directly? These would have been set up previously, but can they be hacked? If I've previously set `$_SESSION['admin']="off"` earlier, and then later use it in a query with `admin=?` where `bind_param` says `("s", $_SESSION['admin']);` is that safe?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do something like `trim($x)`, what comes out is not a variable, it is a reference to the value. The `bind_param` method expects to get a variable for it to work. So, what this means is that you need to do your formatting and other calls **before** you pass it to that function. So yes, your thinking is correct.

For example this is the correct way to do it:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d');
$stmt->bind_param("s", $date);
```

I would recommend you read up on references to get a better understanding: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.php

Comment: Thank you. Does that also mean you can't just input some specific text e.g. `bind_param("s", 'sometext');` without first putting it as a variable?

Comment: Yep. Remember, you are binding a parameter here. If you have a string literal, that can be part of your actual query since there isn't anything to prepare.

Comment: `$stmt = $dbc->prepare("UPDATE something SET this='that' WHERE email=? ");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $email);`   Would that be proper? Is it ok to include 'that' in there?

Comment: Yes that is ok. The biggest reason for prepared statements is to prevent SQL injection from user input. A fixed string like that cannot be changed by a malicious user since it is hard coded in. As for "proper", it depends on the situation. If that is something you want to be configurable, you should make it a variable and bind the parameter like anything else.